# TextFormField validator The argument

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-test, textformfield

I am trying to make a custom widget TextFormField, but the validator: validator, show an error

The argument type `dynamic Function()` can't be assigned to the parameter type `'String? Function(String?)?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable dynamic Function()` validator package:store/widgets/mytextformfield.dart

**mytextformfield.dart <<< file widget TextFormField**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class MyTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() validator;
  final bool obserText;
  final String name;

  const MyTextFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.obserText,
    required this.validator,
    required this.name,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: obserText,
      **validator: validator,**
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: name,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### login.dart

```
MyTextFormField(
      obserText: obserText,
      name: "Email",
          validator: (value) {
          if (value == "") {
         return "Please Fill Email";
        } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value!)) {
          return "Email is Invaild";
        }
      return "";
      },
     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
final Function() validator;
```

To:

```
final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;
```

Comment: now i got error with value on login.dart  >>>> else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value))

Comment: can you share me your error ?

Comment: i change (value)) to ("value")  and work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to define only as `Function` instead of `Function()`:

```
final Function validator;
```

Comment: still not work ! and i tride to declare property validator as:  FormFieldValidator<String>? validator;

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
final Function() validator;
```

With:

```
final FormFieldValidator<String>? validator
```

As it is declared in [TextFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html) class